# Can't install PyAudio on GAE Flexible Environment(Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyaudio

So I am having quite a few issues getting this flask backend up. It is pretty standard stuff apart from some logic that recognizes audio delivered from the frontend. To do this, I incorporate PyDejaVu.

One of the dependencies(PyAudio) is not building correctly. Everything else is good to go.

Here are some logs:

```
Step #1:    #include "portaudio.h"
Step #1:                          ^
Step #1:   compilation terminated.
Step #1:   error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Step #1:   Failed building wheel for PyAudio
```

and

```
Command "/env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-arQ8b7/PyAudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-4yefCE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /env/include/site/python2.7/PyAudio" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-arQ8b7/PyAudio/
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:0d9f13d75152530e2ee49bf3a3be3d6198b946f7315b3961994355a7aaee2925" failed: exit status 1
Step #1: 
------------
```

requirements.txt

```
PyAudio==0.2.9
PyDejaVu==0.1.3
werkzeug==0.14.1
flask-cors==2.1.2
flask-login==0.3.2
flask-oauthlib==0.9.2
flask-restful==0.3.5
flask-wtf==0.12
flask==0.12.2
flask-sqlalchemy==0.9
numpy==1.13.3
gunicorn==19.7.1
```

I followed the errors and apparently I have to install port-audio via apt-get but that obviously is not possible.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your "requirements.txt"? Also are you building your own docker image or you are using App Engine pre-built one? Deploying or running locally? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build

Comment: Yup added. Using the prebuilt container. And deploying.

Answer (score 1):

Since App Engine flex is based on docker you'll have to install dependencies from the Dockerfile. In this case you'd have to customize the App Engine Python [Dockerfile](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime) to add all the libraries PyAudio might need. You could look at some Dockerfiles containing PyAudio [Sample1](https://github.com/theintencity/py-audio/blob/master/Dockerfile) & [Sample2](https://github.com/theintencity/py-audio).

I could go over the error by adding the following dependencies and libraries in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        vim \
        curl \
        wget \
        git \
        make \
        netcat \
        python \
        python2.7-dev \
        g++ \
        bzip2 \
        binutils
###############################################################################
RUN apt-get install -y portaudio19-dev libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev pkg-config git-core cmake python-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-base-dev libblitz0-dev libboost-all-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libqt4-dev libsvm-dev libvlfeat-dev  python-nose python-setuptools python-imaging build-essential libmatio-dev python-sphinx python-matplotlib python-scipy
# additional dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y \
        libasound2 \
        libasound-dev \
        libssl-dev

RUN pip install pyaudio
```