# Install libmagickwand-dev on Google App Engine Flexible - Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, wand

I'm trying to deploy an application on GAE Flexible and this error keeps coming up.

> ImportError at /
>   MagickWand shared library not found.
>   You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
>   Try to install:
>     apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

Locally everything works fine, I've installed `wand` on my virtual env:

`pip install wand`

In my `requirements.txt` I've placed `wand` and the other libraries I am using.

On the prompts logs, after use the command `gcloud app deploy`, one of the logs confirms that the library is sucessfully instaled:

> Step #1: Sucessfully installed Django-1.11.8 .....(other libraries).. wand-0.4.4 wheel-0.30.0

I've already tried to use other versions of wand, until version `wand-0.3.5` Still got the same error.

Is there anyway to acess the GAE terminal to instal the `libmagickwand-dev`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it. I found a link to a similar question:

[Install PyAudio on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531954/cant-install-pyaudio-on-gae-flexible-environmentpython)

So we have to customize the Dockerfile, on terminal type:

```
gcloud beta app gen-config --custom
```

It will create two files in your folder. Open the `Dockerfile` and add these lines:

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app/
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
CMD exec gunicorn -b :$PORT DocAnalysisWeb.wsgi
```

After that, just deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

For me it fixed the problem